# Python-can OSError: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used

Tags: python, python-can

I'm working with CAN cable ECOM, and trying to write a python script to process the messages received from the cable. I came across the python library python-can, but I'm having trouble using it.

When I try to run the code:

```
import can
bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='socketcan', channel='vcan0', bitrate=500000)
```

I get this:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing from this library that's causing the issue?

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem: SocketCan works with Linux system, and I'm on Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following parameters if you are using PCAN on windows via USB:

```
import can    
bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='pcan', channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', bitrate=500000)
```

You can find more help [here.](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/interfaces/pcan.html)

Hope this helps!